# Best way to call Cargo from CMake?

Tags: cmake, rust, rust-cargo

I found this: https://github.com/AndrewGaspar/cmake-cargo but couldn't make it work

Anyway, if I were to use a Makefile instead of CMake, I'd simply create a rule that watches for the .rs files to change and recompile.

I couldn't find a solution for **calling Cargo from Cmake** (not the other way around) so I'm opening one here.

How can I make my `CMakeLists.txt` watch for .rs file changes and recompile by calling `cargo build`?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel in cmake? `cargo build` is already a no-op if no changes have been made, so you could just call it unconditionally.

Comment: Additionally, `.rs` files aren't the only ones a cargo project could rely upon, as it is possible to `include_bytes!` or `include_str!`, which are both things that Cargo will look for when recompiling. I agree with @mcarton, it is probably better if you get Cargo to deal with that.

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna do this way then. Gonna paste here what I did to help others

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the author of the linked project in the OP. I apologize for the sorry state it was in when you found it, but in the last month or so I've invested a bunch of time to really flesh it out, and gave it a more inspiring name: https://github.com/AndrewGaspar/corrosion

I hope you could check out the latest README and let me know if you can get it working for your scenario. And if not, please file an issue, letting me know where in the documentation you ran into issues.

Answer (score 8):

Following recommendations, I simply added the command `cargo build` as a dependency to my library

```
add_library(libsmoltcp_cpp ${libsmoltcp_cpp_sources})

add_custom_target(
    lib_smol_tcp_rust
    COMMAND cargo build
)
add_dependencies(libsmoltcp_cpp lib_smol_tcp_rust)
```